# What is the best way to dynamically access properties for sorting a list?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, reflection, properties

I am populating a virtual listview with the contents of a list of objects. It is a winforms listview control, running on .Net 3.5. I am dynamically generating the columns from the public properties of the object. For this I have used a loop in the constructor of the form:

```
properties = typeof(MyCustomObject).GetProperties().ToArray();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    ColumnHeader ch = new ColumnHeader();
    ch.Text = property.Name;
    listView1.Columns.Add(ch);
}
```

I generate the listviewitems in a listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem handler:

```
MyCustomObject myCustomObject = myCustomObjects[e.ItemIndex];
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(myCustomObject.ID, 0);
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    var propvalue = property.GetValue(myCustomObject, null);
    if (propvalue == null)
        item.SubItems.Add("");
    else
        item.SubItems.Add(propvalue.ToString());
}
```

I need to sort the list of objects in the listView1_ColumnClicked handler when a column is clicked by checking the type of the property for that column. The non-dynamic way to do this would presumably be to write a long if then else statement (or a switch statement) that handles each column:

```
if (sortColumn == 1)
{
    myCustomObjects.Sort(delegate(MyCustomObject o1, MyCustomObject o2)
    {
        DateTime t1 = o1.FirstDate ?? DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime t2 = o2.FirstDate ?? DateTime.MinValue;
        return t1.CompareTo(t2);
    });
}
else if (sortColumn == 2)
{
    myCustomObjects.Sort(delegate(MyCustomObject o1, MyCustomObject o2)
    {
        DateTime t1 = o1.SecondDate ?? DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime t2 = o2.SecondDate ?? DateTime.MinValue;
        return t1.CompareTo(t2);
    });
}
else if (sortColumn == 3)
{
    myCustomObjects.Sort(delegate(MyCustomObject o1, MyCustomObject o2)
    {
        return e1.FirstName.CompareTo(e2.FirstName);
    });
}
else if (sortColumn == 4)
{
    myCustomObjects.Sort(delegate(MyCustomObject o1, MyCustomObject o2)
    {
        return e1.LastName.CompareTo(e2.LastName);
    });
}
else
    // and so on, for each property...
```

This obviously duplicates the code for columns which contain the same data type. I have replaced this with code that uses the property type to determine how to sort the columns:

```
PropertyInfo property = properties[sortColumn];
Type type = property.PropertyType;
if (type == typeof(DateTime))
{
    myCustomObjects.Sort(delegate(MyCustomObject o1, MyCustomObject o2)
    {
        DateTime t1 = (DateTime)property.GetValue(o1, null);
        DateTime t2 = (DateTime)property.GetValue(o2, null);
        return t1.CompareTo(t2);
    });
}
else if (type == typeof(int))
{
    myCustomObjects.Sort(delegate(MyCustomObject o1, MyCustomObject o2)
    {
        int n1 = (int)property.GetValue(o1, null);
        int n2 = (int)property.GetValue(o2, null);
        return n1.CompareTo(n2);
    });
}
else if (type == typeof(string))
{
    myCustomObjects.Sort(delegate(MyCustomObject o1, MyCustomObject o2)
    {
        string s1 = (string)property.GetValue(o1, null);
        string s2 = (string)property.GetValue(o2, null);
        return s1.CompareTo(s2);
    });
}
```

This is working fine, but I have read that performance using reflection can be slow and that there are better ways to do this. I would like to improve my code. How should I dynamically access unknown object properties at runtime in order to sort them?

Answer (score 0):

if you can get column name try to use Dynamic LINQ (http://aonnull.blogspot.com/2010/08/dynamic-sql-like-linq-orderby-extension.html)